# moment-timezone interpret date in certain timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

If I want to build a moment object, representing a timestamp in certain time zone, e.g. 2019/04/13 00:00:00 at time zone Europe/Berlin, how do I do it right?

What I'm trying to do:

```
moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Berlin');
const m = moment('2019/04/13 00:00:00');
```

which results in `m` being set to `Sat Apr 13 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)` - 2 hours ahead of what I need. What I need is 00:00:00 not 02:00:00.

What is the reasoning behind this behavior? How do I tell moment-timezone "take this date and time and interpret it as if it is in the time zone I say"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create time in a specific time zone with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448347/how-to-create-time-in-a-specific-time-zone-with-moment-js)

Comment: @benvc thanks for pointing me to that question, but checking that still didn't clarify why do I get 02:00:00 instead of 00:00:00, applying recommendations from there (e.g. providing format string) didn't fix the issue as well

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, following is a snippet that demonstrates how to apply the answer from the duplicate question.

```js
const berlin = moment.tz('2019/04/13 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss', 'Europe/Berlin');

console.log('UTC', berlin.utc().format());
// UTC 2019-04-12T22:00:00Z

console.log('Europe/Berlin', berlin.tz('Europe/Berlin').format());
// Europe/Berlin 2019-04-13T00:00:00+02:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```