# Get UTC offset from timezone abbreviations

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Is there anyway to get utc offset from a timezone abbreviations? Such as:

> "PST"

for

> Pacific Standard Time (North America)

which will result in **UTC−08**. I found a way on moment-timezone but it did not help much.
It provides a list of timezone identifier but most of them are deprecated.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you found using moment-timezone and how that wasn’t helpful?

Comment: As I said, it provides a list of identifier but most of them are deprecated.

Comment: I think it does not help much when I show the list to end user for choosing their timezone

Comment: If the goal is to let the user select their timezone, you shouldn't use the timezone abbreviations in the first place. You should use timezones like "Europe/London". 'Cause such timezones switch between "abbreviation timezones" at different times of the year.

Comment: does moment change it automatically? Between normal and DST

Comment: If you use a timezone like "Europe/London" and you create a timestamp with that or you do some date calculations (e.g. adding "6 months" to a timestamp) or you convert a timestamp from one timezone to another, then yes, DST will be handled properly. That's the point of those kinds of timezones.

Comment: Thank you very much. I find a way through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a quite tricky topic and similar questions have already been discussed.

See [Detect timezone abbreviation using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954397/detect-timezone-abbreviation-using-javascript) or
[Get timezone abbreviation using offset value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374901/get-timezone-abbreviation-using-offset-value)

I would propose two options:

**1. Hash table**. Create a key-value pair of what you require based on standard information (e.g. list of timezone abbreviations and their offset). Something like

```
    let offsetByAbbrev = {"PST" : "UTC-08", "EST" : "UTC+01", ... }
```

But this needs serious maintenance as it will get deprecated quickly.

**2. Date manipulation**. You can create a date in a specific timezone with momentjs, however, not with abbreviations. And there is a good reason for it: these abbreviations can change and can also cause ambiguity. You can check out the JSON used by momentjs-timezone: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json which will give you a general sense of how chaotic it can be. For example do a simple ctrl+f search for PST and see the results.

So I would suggest using the timezone names - which you can actually create and use with momentjs-timezone. See [How to create time in a specific time zone with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448347/how-to-create-time-in-a-specific-time-zone-with-moment-js) where you can create a moment object based on the timezone name and that object will contain (as per the spec of moment timezone: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/) the offset itself.

I know this does not exactly resolve your problem, though what you are trying to do is not necessarily the best approach to reach your an ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks for your explaining. I know what to do now.