# How to create a momentJS object with a specfic time and a specific timezone(other than the default local time zone)?

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I will receive an string(with time and date) from the frontend. The string format is this "2021-08-16T23:15:00.000Z".  I intend to declare a moment object with the input string, along with a specific timezone(other than the local one).

```js
    import moment from "moment";
    import "moment-timezone";



    // The input string I receive from the frontend.
    let strTime = "2021-08-16T23:15:00.000Z";

    console.log(strTime); //2021-08-16T23:15:00.000Z
    let time = moment.tz(strTime,  "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ","America/Boise");

    console.log(time); // Moment<2021-08-16T17:15:00-06:00>, undesired value
    let UTCtime = moment.utc(time);
    console.log(UTCtime);
```

As far as what I understood from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18449364/12247181) question, `console.log(time)` should output a moment object of time 23:15:00, but with timezone "America/Boise".

What I intend is `time` to have the same time i.e "23:15:00.000", with "America/Boise" as timezone.
So that when I later convert that time to UTC, I need to get the right value w.r.t the timezone "America/Boise" and not my local timezone. How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

```js
    const momenttz = require("moment-timezone");
    const moment = require("moment");
    
    // The input string I receive from the frontend.
    let strTime = "2021-08-16T23:15:00.000Z";
    console.log(strTime); //2021-08-16T23:15:00.000Z
    
    let time = moment.utc(strTime);
    time.tz("America/Boise", true);
    console.log(time.tz());
    
    console.log(time); // Moment<2021-08-16T23:15:00-06:00>, desired value
    
    let UTCtime = moment.utc(time);
    console.log(UTCtime); // Moment<2021-08-17T05:15:00Z>
```

In the above code, at `console.log(time)`,`time` has the value "23:15:00.000" with required timezone "America/Boise". This makes it possible for you to get the right value , when you later convert it to UTC.

This is made possible by passing an optional second parameter to `.tz` mutator of `moment-timezone` as `true` which changes only the timezone (and its corresponding offset), and does not affect the time value.

```js
    time.tz(timezone, true);
```

A sample example of using this is given in the answer code above.

You can read more about it [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) in the *Moment Timezone Documentation*